# Return value from a model in magento

Tags: php, magento, model

I am learning magento. I have a model which is given below.

```
class Kaushikamdotcom_Test_Model_Validator extends Varien_Object {

    private $errors = array();

    public function validate($_post) {
        $validator = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
        $validator->setMessages(
            array(
                Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => "This field cannot be empty"
            )
        );
        if(isset($_post['save'])) {
            if(! $validator->isValid($_post['title'])) {
                $this->errors['title'] = "This field cannot be empty";      
            }
            if(! $validator->isValid($_post['filename'])) {
                $this->errors['filename'] = "This field cannot be empty";
            }
        }
    }

    public function getErrors() {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}
```

In the controller I use the **validate** method as below:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $validator = Mage::getSingleton('test/validator');      
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $validator->validate($this->getRequest()->getPost());
    }
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

I invoke the model in the block (Extended from **Mage_Core_Block_Template**) like below:

```
public function _construct() {
   $this->validator = Mage::getSingleton('test/validator');
   $this->errors = $this->validator->getErrors();
   parent::_construct();
}
```

The following code gives me return value

```
public function getError($_key) {
   $errors = $this->validator->getErrors();
   return (isset($errors[$_key])) ? $errors[$_key] : '';
}
```

Instead of the above code if use the following code it does not give any return value

```
public function getError($_key) {
   return (isset($this->errors[$_key])) ? $this->errors[$_key] : '';
}
```

As we have initialized `$this->errors` in the construct function why it is not returning any values ?

Comment: You only have one underscore in front of construct: _construct instead of __construct.

Comment: That works here as there is a function with the same name in Mage_Core_Block_Template.

Comment: @BennyHill Magento blocks and model objects have an internal `_construct` method, which functions similar to PHP's native constructor.

Comment: @kaushik, what is the output of Zend_Debug::dump($this->errors)? Is it an array as expected, does it contain keys which you can search against?

Comment: kaushik - sorry, I'm not familiar with Magento, I wasn't aware of the _construct method name. @AlanStorm - thanks for pointing that out :-)

Comment: Does not give any return value or returns an empty string?

Comment: When I put the **loadlayout** after validation in the controller; it works. In the above code validation works after the population of the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not enough information in the question to provide a concrete answer, but in general terms it's not returning any values because your `errors` array doesn't have the key you're passing in **at the time you're populating it**.

This is a guess, but your call to

```
$this->validator->getErrors();
```

looks like it returns a PHP array, not an object.  So, when you're calling it in `_construct`, `getErrors` is returning an empty array.

However, between `_construct` being called and you calling `getError`, something about system state changes (likely the form and/or information you're trying to validate is created), so a new call to

```
$this->validator->getErrors();
```

returns a new PHP array, this one populated with error messages. However, the following code

```
public function getError($_key) {
   return (isset($this->errors[$_key])) ? $this->errors[$_key] : '';
}
```

only references the empty array that was populated during `_construct`.  PHP arrays aren't quite objects — they behave more like primitive values.  It will **not** automatically update itself.

Comment: When I put the **loadlayout** after validation in the controller it works. Thank you for your answer. I have been reading your articles. They are just great.